# RSpec returning 'undefined local variable or method `signin_path''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run RSpec I am getting 4 errors all stating:

```
undefined local variable or method `signin_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x4203fa8>
```

But I am running other tests that use this helper and path with no problem, it is only in the relationship controller tests that do not work with it.

relationship_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RelationshipsController do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { sign_in user }

    describe "creating a relationship with Ajax" do

        it "should increment the Relationship count" do
            expect do
                xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
            end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "should respond with success" do
            xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
            response.should be_success
        end
    end

    describe "destroying a relationship with Ajax" do

        before { user.follow!(other_user) }
        let(:relationship) { user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user) }

        it "should decrement the Relationship count" do
            expect do
                xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
            end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
        end

        it "should respond with success" do
            xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
            response.should be_success
        end
    end
end
```

Utilities.rb:

```
def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in 'Email',        with: user.email.upcase
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign In'
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :sessions,      only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
  resources :microposts,    only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  # Application Root
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  # Static Pages
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  # Users
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

Comment: i was getting similar problems and following this got it solved:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507413/hartl-chapter-11-ajax-undefined-local-variable-or-method-cookies

Answer (score 1):

Controller specs cannot interact with pages in the same way that feature specs do, so your `sign_in` utility will not work for them.

If your controller specs rely on a signed-in user, you will need to stub your `current_user` method. If you use Devise, here's a helpful page from their wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Comment: I am following the Rails Tutorial and it instructs me to write that and then says the tests should pass so I'm not sure if it's him or me that is wrong, also what do you mean when you say 'stub your `current_user` method'?

Comment: *I'm not sure if it's him or me that is wrong*. It's you. `visit`, `fill_in`, etc. only work in feature/integration specs; they don't work in controller specs.

Comment: @zetetic but I was told to put that by the tutorial, can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: shouldn't it be sign_in_path?